# Appropriate language for scripting gathering server information tasks?

Tags: logging, powershell

I have a fairly unique problem, and I'd like to gather some input on it.

I'm responsible for creating a script of some sort that can do the following things:

- Run on any Windows Server 2008 R2 server
- Set up and run Perfmon Counters
- Log these counters to a log file
- Roll the log file when it gets too large

The script needs to be able to have the following properties:

- Compatible with WPF or Winforms (I need to create a GUI for it)
- Can be run by a local administrator on any Windows Server 2008 R2 server
- Is portable (as in, it can be easily packaged and put on a thumb drive, etc., with minimal (or no) installer overhead)
- Can be run by a user with little/no technical expertise (this goes back to the need to have a GUI)

So far I've gone down the road of Powershell, because it seems to fulfill most of the requirements. However, with how Powershell's security is set up I either need to have the script force an unrestricted script policy, or I need to figure out a way to create a self-signed certificate on any machine that might use it.

It's that last bit that causes problems, because makecert.exe requires that the user put in a password/key for the certificate (thus confusing a non-technical user) and isn't guaranteed to exist in a production Windows Server 2008 environment (thus forcing the user to install the Windows SDK or Visual Studio).

So I wanted to see if there was another language out there that could fulfill the requirements above, to make sure I'm using the right tool for the job.

NOTE: I'm not planning on using the scripting language itself to create the GUI, that can be done via VB or C# or something else. The script just needs to be called by a winform or WPF. Those are being used because I am most used to using Visual Studio rather than any other IDE.

Comment: You want to create GUI with PowerShell? Much easier to go with C# IMO.

Comment: @Aryadev I'm planning to use VB or C# to create the GUI and call the <whatever> script from there, the script itself just needs to be able to be called from elsewhere easily. So I guess that just means interpreted. I'll edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: I'd create it all in C#. It's easier to handle the security problems, and doesn't require the clients to run the same PowerShell version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track and this should take care of your last concern.

I have quoted relevant lines from the powershell help file on [about_Execution_Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847748.aspx)

> You can set an execution policy for the local computer, for the current
>       user, or for a particular session.
>
> The execution policy for a particular session
>       is stored only in memory and is lost when the session is closed.

You don't need to sign your scripts to make your powershell scripts portable. The execution policy for a powershell session can be set by using -ExecutionPolicy parameter when calling powershell.exe. This does not effect or change the execution policy that is already set on the computer.

For example, your GUI can call the script *Install-Perfmon.ps1* using the commandline:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File Install-Permon.ps1
```

This will work even the computer has a stricter execution policy already set.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for that help, I just gave that a shot (although instead of Unrestricted I used Bypass so there's less of a chance of a warning), and it works just fine. Now I'm on to creating the GUI.